# Undefined index (2)

Tags: php

I have a little problem here.
Can you help me with this error?

"Notice: Undefined index:"

My code:

```
<?php
  $a1 = $_GET['scitovanie_1'];    //error 
  $a2 = $_GET['scitovanie_2'];    //error
  $b1 = $_GET['odcitovanie_1'];   //error
  $b2 = $_GET['odcitovanie_2'];   //error
  $c1 = $_GET['nasobenie_1'];     //error
  $c2 = $_GET['nasobenie_2'];     //error
  $d1 = $_GET['delenie_1'];       //error
  $d2 = $_GET['delenie_2'];       //error

  if($a1 AND $a2){
    $vysledok = $a1 + $a2;

    echo $vysledok;
  }else if($b1 AND $b2){
    $vysledok = $b1 - $b2;

    echo $vysledok;
  }else if($c1 AND $c2){
    $vysledok = $c1 * $c2;

    echo $vysledok;
  }else{
if($d1 AND $d2){
    $vysledok = $d1 / $d2;

    echo $vysledok;
  }
}
?>
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: use isset( $_GET[ index ]) at first to make sure you receive those parameters in $_GET

Comment: please show full error @Radoslav Rác

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for all `response` variable if `isset` or `not` manually

```
$a1 = isset($_GET['scitovanie_1'])?$_GET['scitovanie_1']:"";
```

for all variable so if not set than set value blank

Comment: It is working thank you. Can you explain me why i must add ?$_GET['scitovanie_1']:""    ?

Comment: because it is for checking that variable exists or not some variable which we get from the may be set or some may be not so for checking the presence of variable we can use this,for more info you can check following link:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: bcoz if value (?) than set to variable else(:) assign "" empty string to varibale